# Cant resolve nested Resource

Tags: wpf, user-controls, resources

I got following Source

```
<UserControl.Resources>
   <DataTemplate x:Key="ItemTemplate">
      <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Inventory}" 
                             ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
                             ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"   
                             ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ItemChildTemplate}"
                             ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource ListBoxChildItemStyle}"
                             BorderThickness="0">
      </ListBox>
   </DataTemplate>
   <DataTemplate x:Key="ItemChildTemplate"> ... </DataTemplate>
   <Style x:Key="ListBoxChildItemStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">...</Style>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

I get:

The resource `ListBoxChildItemStyle` could not be resolved.

The resource `ItemChildTemplate` could not be resolved.

I don't see the problem at all.  Expression Blend also has no suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Resources need to be declared *before* being referenced statically. Swap the order of your resources so that you never reference one that appears later in your file.